# Union of generics in array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to get the union type of generics in an array but can only retrieve what the generic is extended from not the actual implementation.

```
type Params = Record<string, number | string | null | undefined> | undefined;
type Route<T extends Params = undefined> = {
  params: T
}
type Stack = {
  routes: Route<Params>[];
}

const route1: Route<{ detailUrl: string }> = { ... };
const route2: Route<{ head: string }> = { ... };
const route3: Route = { ... };

const routeRegistry: Stack = {
  routes: [route1, route2, route3]
};
```

```
type UnionOfParams = ExtractGeneric<typeof routeRegistry['routes'][number]>;
// expected: { detailUrl: string } | { head: string } | undefined
// received: Params
```

I know const assertion is useful to limit widening of the inference of the types, but using it in this case didn't produce any result.

I couldn't find anything related to this particular problem. Is there a way to accomplish what I ask?

Comment: You didn't include `ExtractGeneric`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have inference and an annotation for a variable. This can only be done with a function. A function can have a generic type parameter that both constrains a parameter and offers a vehicle for inference:

```
function createRouteRegistry<T extends Stack>(p: T): T {
  return p
}

const routeRegistry = createRouteRegistry({
  routes: [route1, route2, route3]
})

type ExtractGeneric<T> = T extends Route<infer P> ? P : never
type UnionOfParams = ExtractGeneric<typeof routeRegistry['routes'][number]>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQEoQMYD2CAJgDyrAICWAdgOYA0UNArsgEYQJQA+UF1er2YsANqOEsaxCADNaEYgD5J0uQuIBuAFChIOAi2ARSAFSgQAHsenp4SNJihSZ8mopVYA3tqhQwiCioAFxQptoAvrrg0ADKwHB4ANZOPn4IhsYhBkYm9kFKANoAujpR2oQ0FFAZuQCModiZJl5QMglUogCqCKKhArR0UBGeIuIAhDqV1bXGAEyNzaStABYQcMT9lIPDo6wTUwRVwDXNAMyLuU77opPa2rJSeMBUR1B4COvGTbm4dFQCEBmCzWCC2KDxRJJJQACjAoVMAEoEVA0jUIMAWAgaP5IvdpidZhA-gDKCAnB8vsTmiTATC0UTsoUiXUmES5mzzsVIoj7npoABRaxIZ4AcTBXCoeDMo3MVhsxHQP2MpFosi4sBUAH5YFBQu4AG5caL6Lo0V40ADysnyjiwQsoiWA4vc1Gl-IIslOvwg-0BhQA5IyA8VCqwOFxikodAB6GOotoYuCdHp9fjbIQRYSrdabdOCIZZvgudTuYjaIA)

Comment: sorry, the type of routeRegistry should be Stack, I updated the code in question.

Comment: @HakanÖzdemir if the type of `routeRegistry` has to be `Stack` then there is no information captured about what actual params were passed in. Do you want to constrain the type to `Stack` while capturing the actual type ?

Comment: Yes. There would be several 'routeRegistry's in my actual code so I want each of them to contain only routes with type Route<Param>. So yes, I both want to constrain them to Route<Params> and capture actual Params implemented.